# Setting the Frequency of a timeseries Pandas Dataframe with Two index Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe, "df", which has a datetime index and another **index** column called "Location":

```
                        V1   V2  
Date       Location             
2001-01-01  1           0.5  0.7
            2           0.6  0.5
2001-01-02  3           0.8  0.2
            4           0.8  0.2
2001-01-03  5           0.2  0.4
            6           0.2  0.5
2001-01-04  7           0.2  0.3
            8           0.8  0.7
```

As you can see, the dataframe has multiple observations under the same date.

To be able to use some statistical packages, I have to set the frequency of the dataframe to "days" using this method:

```
df = df.asfreq('d')
```

However, the dataframe has two index columns; one datetime and another which is not. When I tried to set frequency using the approach which is in the captioned codeblock, I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [(Timestamp('2002-07-23
>   00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), '1')] of type  to
>   Timestamp

If I try to set just the date as the index column, I end up with the case of the same date appearing multiple times in the frame. In short; Pandas interprets these repeated instances as duplicates.

How would you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `MultiIndex`, so possible solution is reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) first for `DatetimeIndex` and then reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.unstack().asfreq('d').stack()
print (df)
                      V1   V2
Date       Location          
2001-01-01 1         0.5  0.7
           2         0.6  0.5
2001-01-02 3         0.8  0.2
           4         0.8  0.2
2001-01-03 5         0.2  0.4
           6         0.2  0.5
2001-01-04 7         0.2  0.3
           8         0.8  0.7
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to "set" the frequency of a series with a multi index. A multi-index series just can't have a frequency - maybe to avoid dealing with multiple datetime columns in the index, etc